# Meteor (mrt) package loaded but "Model is not defined" error occured

Tags: javascript, meteor

I installed the [models package](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-models) from Atmosphere via mrt.

```
meteor add models
```

says `models: already using`.

when I insert a `console.log` statement in the `model.js` file located at this package it get executed and logged before the error occured.

```
I2036-22:23:13.047(1)? MODEL LOADING     <-- (my console.log)
W2036-22:23:13.054(1)? (STDERR) /home/user/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W2036-22:23:13.054(1)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W2036-22:23:13.055(1)? (STDERR)                               ^
W2036-22:23:13.057(1)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: Model is not defined
```

any idea why this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package seems to be not updated to use with Meteor 0.6.5 and later. In that version the smart package API has changed, so older packages can no longer be used without a (simple) update.

The package in question seem to be only an experiment, quote:

> This is a basic proof of concept of the way meteor models could work

Are you sure you need it for your task?

If so, you should clone that package and update the `package.js` file to use `api.export` method. Alternatively, if you just want to experiment, you can specify Meteor release in your project to be less than 0.6.5.

Comment: thank you. I know that's only a poc, but I wanted to playing around with basic model functionality in meteor.